# Changing the initial file location of NodeJS app on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, azure, typescript

I have a NodeJS app on Azure which was written in Javascript. The `app.js` was in the root directory and was detected automatically when deploying to Azure via Git.

I recently converted the app to Typescript with a build directory, so the root file is now in `dist/app.js`.

When debugging in VS Code, I can easily change `launch.json` to point to the new location, however now when pushing changes to Azure it no longer works.

How do I specifiy the launch file for Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `web.config` in your root directory of your application.

Modify the `<handlers>` tag:

```
<handlers>
    <!-- Indicates that the app.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <add name="iisnode" path="/dist/app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
</handlers>
```

Modify the rewirte mod :

```
<rule name="DynamicContent">
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="dist\app.js"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I don't have access to this file - it is autogenned when I upload to Azure. Also, is it forwardslash for path, and backslash in the url?

Comment: Yes, you are right. As it is automatically created by Azure, but when it be created, we can modify it. You can use FTP or the **App Service Editor** extension in Azure portal to modify the file.